# Alternative group by solution

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have the following query

```
$sql="
select mp.*
     , u.*
     , rp.* 
  from monthly_payments mp 
  left 
  join users u 
    on u.id = mp.tenant_id 
  left 
  join rentalagreements rp 
    on rp.id = mp.rentalagreement_id 
 where mp.completed_payment = 0 
   and mp.paydate > CURDATE() 
 group 
    by mp.tenant_id
";
```

This is the error i retrieve:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'mp.id' isn't in GROUP BY
```

I have read that i need to use every column in the select clause, but i am using 3 tables and that seems awk to have to define every column in every table inside the group by.

is there an alternative solution?

Comment: Generally, using GROUP BY without an aggregation function (like SUM, AVG, COUNT) is usually a sign of another problem. Most likely, your server only allows standard GROUP BY use, which means all non-aggregated fields must be in the GROUP BY You _should_ just be able to use DISTINCT, but since this kind of use for GROUP BY is usually used to compensate for records wrongly considered "duplicate" that may not be an option for you. Also, `SELECT *` is generally bad form for anything but "dev" (non-application) queries.

Comment: The query as it stands is gibberish (or, at best 'indeterminate'). Never include a GROUP BY clause in a query absent of any aggregating functions. If you want distinct results, use DISTINCT. In this instance, either all results are distinct anyway, or you have larger problems with your data model!

Comment: @Strawberry youre right thanks